# Spring ws Unauthorized [401]

Tags: spring-mvc, jaxb, spring-ws, jaxb2

I'm trying to consume a soap service. The service has no certificate, but receives as a property of the request username and password.
but I'm getting the following error:

```
org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceTransportException: Unauthorized [401]
```

I tried in several ways to pass the username and password.
Using the soapui I was able to make the requisition. In soapui I pass the username and password through request properties.

```
 @Bean
    Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        jaxb2Marshaller.setPackagesToScan("ce.gov.s2gpr.compras.licita.business.model.service.bean");
        return jaxb2Marshaller;
    }


    @Bean
    public WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate() {
        WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate();
        webServiceTemplate.setMarshaller(jaxb2Marshaller());
        webServiceTemplate.setUnmarshaller(jaxb2Marshaller());
        webServiceTemplate.setDefaultUri(defaultUri);

        HttpsUrlConnectionMessageSender sender = new HttpsUrlConnectionMessageSender();
        sender.setTrustManagers(new TrustManager[] {
                new X509TrustManager() {
                    public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        return null;
                    }
                    public void checkClientTrusted(
                            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                    }
                    public void checkServerTrusted(
                            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                    }
                }
        });

        webServiceTemplate.setMessageSenders(new WebServiceMessageSender[]{sender, httpComponentsMessageSender()});

        return webServiceTemplate;
    }


    @Bean
    public HttpComponentsMessageSender httpComponentsMessageSender() {
        HttpComponentsMessageSender httpComponentsMessageSender = new HttpComponentsMessageSender();
        httpComponentsMessageSender.setConnectionTimeout(timeout);
        httpComponentsMessageSender.setReadTimeout(DEFAULT_READ_TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS);
        httpComponentsMessageSender.setReadTimeout(timeout);
        httpComponentsMessageSender.setCredentials(new UsernamePasswordCredentials(userName, userPassword));

        return httpComponentsMessageSender;
    }
```

I tried in several ways to pass the username and password, but I received the same error.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public AtualizacaoItensGruposResponse testeSoap(PgeTO dto) {

    ObjectFactory factory = new ObjectFactory();

    AtualizacaoItensGrupos itens = factory.createAtualizacaoItensGrupos();

    itens.setArg0(dto);
    JAXBElement<AtualizacaoItensGrupos> request =  factory.createAtualizacaoItensGrupos(itens);

    try {

        WebServiceMessageCallback wsCallback = message -> {
            TransportContext context = TransportContextHolder.getTransportContext();
            WebServiceConnection connection = context.getConnection();
            HttpUrlConnection conn = (HttpUrlConnection) connection;

            conn.getConnection().setRequestProperty("Username", "");
            conn.getConnection().setRequestProperty("Password", "");
            conn.getConnection().setRequestProperty("username", "");
            conn.getConnection().setRequestProperty("password", "");

            conn.getConnection().addRequestProperty("Username", "");
            conn.getConnection().addRequestProperty("Password", "");
            conn.getConnection().addRequestProperty("username", "");
            conn.getConnection().addRequestProperty("password", "");
            conn.getConnection().addRequestProperty("s2gpr.integracao.cotacao.item_licitacao.webservice.user", "");
            conn.getConnection().addRequestProperty("s2gpr.integracao.cotacao.item_licitacao.webservice.password", "");
        };

        webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(request, wsCallback);
        return null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage());
        throw new ClientLicitaWebException("Ocorreu um erro ao enviar as informações para o sistema LicitaWeb");
    }

}
```

Comment: *"but receives as a property of the request username and password"* - what does this mean, exactly? HTTP headers or what?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebServiceTransportException: Unauthorized \[401\] in Spring-WS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115557/webservicetransportexception-unauthorized-401-in-spring-ws)

Comment: It is not duplicity, it needs to pass the credentials. I need to pass the requisition.

Comment: I found out how to solve it. used:
public void doWithMessage(WebServiceMessage message) throws IOException, TransformerException {
        SaajSoapMessage soapMessage2 = (SaajSoapMessage) message;
        MimeHeaders mimeHeader = soapMessage2.getSaajMessage().getMimeHeaders();
        mimeHeader.setHeader("Authorization", getB64Auth(userName, userPassword));
    }